# tostring vs. tofile for creating raw binary files

Tags: python, numpy

I need to save a numpy array to a raw binary file, and based on advice from colleagues, I understand that `tostring` and `tofile` should be doing roughly the same thing. However, when I run

```
x=np.load('foo.npy')
(open('foo_1.dat', 'w')).write(x.T.tostring())
x.T.tofile('foo_2.dat')
np.all(np.fromfile('foo_1.dat') == np.fromfile('foo_2.dat'))
```

`False` is returned. Can anyone explain to me why this is the case, or if I am doing something wrong, where I can correct the code to make my end products equivalent?

EDIT:
Using this method, foo_1.dat and foo_2.dat have the same data type (float64), HOWEVER, the shape is different (tostring = 38497230L, tofile =38407680L).
I need to transpose the files for a program-specific application, and am not using np.save because I specifically need .dat files.

Comment: We need to see more information about the `fromfile` results. Shape, dtype, even actual small arrays. Why are you saving the transpose? And why not stick with `np.save`, which worked for `foo.npy`?

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but the file should be opened in binary mode: `open('foo_1.dat', 'wb')`

Answer (score 0):

> > I don't know if this is the issue, but the file should be opened in binary >>mode: open('foo_1.dat', 'wb')

That was it! Thank you!